# Dynamic bean creation spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

My api input contains "customInformation" means the user can give their information irrespective of conditions.

Based on the given fields i need to create a bean with given input details to process the input.

is the way is applicable or not?
If there,can you please privide a way to solve it?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Please provide the code that you tried so far

Comment: I have not started , Just i created the input beans. I am in confusion to go with next step

Comment: What about api? At least you should write that code @madhuri

Comment: @PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE) 
public String createApi(HttpServletRequest request,@RequestHeader(value =tenantId) String theTenantId,@RequestBody @NotNull String theData) {                     
    
 --------   
 return output;     }